# Multiply Background with two different colors for two sections

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I am trying to apply two different `background-color` with `background-blend-mode: multiply;`.  See image: 
[image: Image with two different multiplied colors].

I have tried something similar to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raney24/vhs0cxrd/).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.wrap {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/2324/skyline-buildings-new-york-skyscrapers.jpg") fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: relative;
}
.row {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <h1>
     Header
  </h1>
</div>
```